# Function OnCollisionEnter is not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I've written code for destroying the player if it collides with an obstacle. But I get the error

> The local function 'OnCollisionEnter' is declared but never used

My Code:

```cs
void Update()
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag = "Player")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't define a method inside of another method. You need to put the OnCollisionEnter function outside of the Update Function scope.

Comment: @MathewHD nitpick: actually [you can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). But you're correct about OP's scoping problem.

Comment: Ah nice to now I was wondering why his program didn't throw any other errors but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
void Update()
{
    
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag = "Player")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to make it understandable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can theoretically define a function in your Update Method, they are called [Local Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions).

But you can't do that with Unitys prepgroammed Functions eg. `Start()`, `Update()`, `OnTriggerEnter()`, `OnCollisioEnter()`.

What you need to do instead, is take out your `OnCollisionEnter()` Function from the locally defined Update scope and instead place it into the MonoBehaviour Scope.

**Example:**

```cs
private void Update() {
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    // Use CompareTag to get Error Message, 
    // when the Tag doesn't exist in the Scene
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

**Unrelated:**

I would also generally advise you to use `CompareTag()` instead of `gameObjec.tag == ""`. Because CompareTag will throw an Error if there is no such Tag in your Scene and is therefore pretty usefull when you made a typo with the name of the Tag.